# adding a background-image to body in a cakephp layout with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2 and I'm trying to allow my users to upload an image which is then used as the background for their page.

I have the images uploading fine and saving to a (webroot)files/User/$userid/$bodybgimage. I've also got the name of the image in the database.

Trouble is I want because I don't know in advance what user id is going to be requesting their background image I can't put their background in the stylesheet, so I'm trying to get it added in the default layout. I've tried to add with jquery: (the image filename is in $bodybgimage)

```
<?php if(!$bodybgimage == '') {?>
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url('<?php echo '../files/User/'.$userId.'/'.$bodybgimage; ?>')');
    <?php  }?>
```

But this seems to just remove everystyle I had for the body!

I also tried doing adding it straight to the body tag like so:

```
<body<?php if(!$bodybgimage == '') echo ' style="background-image:url(../files/User/'.$userId.'/'.$bodybgimage.')"';?>>
```

But again to no avail. Can anyone help me out. I know the image and all's there because if I put the background-image style in the stylesheet the image pops up ok. There must be a sensible way to do this that I'm missing. Plz help!

Comment: I think in the first code you have a javascript problem. The first ' in the url part will terminate the string. You should quote it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. I changed it to $('body').css('background-image', 'url("<?php echo "../files/User/".$userId."/".$bodybgimage; ?>")'); (and various alternatives) but still no luck. I'm new to javascript not sure of the correct syntax

Comment: WooHoo! I got it with: $('body').css('background-image', 'url(<?php echo $this->webroot."/files/User/".$userId."/".$bodybgimage; ?>)');

Answer (score 0):

Please can you try to omit the "../" before the files as i assume that your images founded in a folder named files beside your script not ?